# How to fix one or more hunks were rejected in the patch you just applied error?

Tags: git, git-patch, git-apply

While applying patch in git, I am getting the below error if I have same files modified in working copy which were there in patch.

> One or more hunks were rejected in the patch you just applied, you
>   will find the hunk in '.rej' files of the same name as the file
>   affected. The files affected are : D D..

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm the contens of rejected hunk in '.rej' files.

you can run `git difftool` to launch a diff tool to view the difference side by side, and determine how to apply those patch.

Update:

For how to read .rej file, you can refer to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542895/how-to-read-rej-files-i-e)

For how to use `git difftool` ,you can refer to [this page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)

Comment: could you provide some example (if you have)?